# Apple Clang; using C++11 with libstdc++

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, llvm, libstdc++

I have an issue when compiling a simple Hello file with an empty function taking `initializer_list` argument when using both `-stdlib=libstdc++` and `-std=c++11`

If I use only `-std=c++11` (which means compiling with libc++)

then the file compiles and prints Hello!

If I comment `function_test` and I use both `-std=c++11` and `-stdlib=libstdc++`

then the file compiles and prints Hello!

If I keep the function `function_test` and I use both `-std=c++11` and `-stdlib=libstdc++`

then I get the following error:

```
$ g++ -stdlib=libstdc++  -std=c++11   -o test test.cpp
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'initializer_list' file not found
#include <initializer_list>
          ^
1 error generated.
```

Here is my file

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void function_test(initializer_list<int> something){}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   cout << "Hello!" << endl;
   function_test({0});
   return 0;
}
```

Here is my apple clang version

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: is intializer_list available in the include directory?

Comment: A simple `g++ --std=c++11 -o test test.cpp` would work.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès yes this works fine as I stated in the question. However I need to use another library that is compiled with libstdc++ so I need to combile my file with libstdc++ and not with the standard library of clang that is libC++

Comment: @Pooya That's what you'd expect of standard library headers, right?

Comment: @Angew: that's right but I have encountered several cases where according to bad installation some of the header files were missing

Comment: @Pooya if the header was missing then it shouldn't compile with -std=c++11 either. Or does clang use different headers when compiling with libstdc++ and libc++ ? how can I check that?

Comment: @IssamT: if you look at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/dir_e96818ea44b74decf0d0168e5ad4fe6f.html you will find that initializer_list is not in the include directory of libstdc++

Comment: Of course different headers are used when you switch the standard library implementation. Almost all of the C++ standard library is header-only.

Comment: Then you may separate compilation and link edition and provide the lib at link-time... You need to forbid the libstdc++ at compile-time.

Answer (score 6):

```
--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
                                       ^^^^^^^
```

Notice the "4.2". Your libstdc++ is *way* to old for C++11. Upgrade it to some 5.x version for full C++11 support.

Comment: That's weird the computer is a new mac. It has less than 1 year. and the llvm version seem to be one of the latest versions. how can libstdc++ that clang installed be so old?

Comment: libstdc++ is still there for backwards compatibility. For applications compiled with older Xcode versions. C++11 functionality was added in the "new" libc++ library meant as a replacement for the old one.

Comment: Apple doesn't do GPL-3.  4.2 was the last gcc under GPL-2.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Not an Apple user, but I believe one can install the modern gccs under Apple ("Homebrew" or smth like that) and once one has that going, one can probably tell clang to use the modern libstdc++.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that upgrading to a newer version of libstdc++ is just not possible with apple-llvm(clang). So using some features of C++11 with libstdc++ is not possible. The reason is this one:

> Mainline libstdc++ has switched to GPL3, a license which the
>   developers of libc++ cannot use. libstdc++ 4.2 (the last GPL2 version)
>   could be independently extended to support C++11, but this would be a
>   fork of the codebase (which is often seen as worse for a project than
>   starting a new independent one). Another problem with libstdc++ is
>   that it is tightly integrated with G++ development, tending to be tied
>   fairly closely to the matching version of G++.

source:
http://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/

Thanks to all the answers/comments that helped me reach the answer.

Comment: Do you need libstdc++? If you do you can always install GCC from macports or homebrew.

Comment: @kometen Yes because I m using a library that is compiled with it and I don't have its sources to recompile it.

Comment: OK, I'll remove my answer which is not correct then.

Comment: Actually, I believe you can just install a complete modern gcc including libstdc++ on a mac. Then you can either compile with gcc + libstdc++ or (probably) tell clang where to find the new libstdc++.

Comment: libc++ and libstdc++ happily co-exist in a binary. This is fine so long as you aren't passing STL into the interface of your legacy component built with libstdc++

Comment: @BaummitAugen yes that's possible I think, but you need to compile clang from the sources and when running cmake provide the option -DGCC_INSTALL_PREFIX. However i m not sure if it is possible for apple-clang...

Comment: @marko thanks. I didn't know about this, although it doesn't help in my situation.